# Flutter Firebase reduce firebase storage bandwith and requests

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

So I really hope somebody can help me out. At the moment im working on my app with firebase. Now I have like 4 test users and 6 test videos with 1min length and around 3-5mb size in my app. While developing around 3 hours, firebase tells me that I reached the daily usage limits of the free plan and I have to wait 24 hours.

For example right now I have 716 requests and a total of 2.5gb bandwith, but only 19mb data in total in my bucket. I think it's actually the bandwith which results in the lockdown of my usage.

How can I actually track the exact requests, bandwith and so on in my flutter app or on any other way? Is there a tool or something?

And how to reduce the value bandwith actually? any ideas?
My Database model looks like the following:

```
videos
-------- ID
------------ Name
------------ Videolink (firebase storage)
------------ CoverImage (firebase storage)
------------ CreatorID

users
-------- ID
------------- Name
------------- FirstName
------------- ....

userFavoriteVideos
------------------- userId
----------------------------- videoId
---------------------------------- true
----------------------------- videoId
---------------------------------- true
----------------------------- videoId
---------------------------------- true
------------------- userId
------------------- userId
```

Appreciate any improvments, approaches or experience to my question.
Thank you!

Comment: You might find useful [this documentation page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/monitor-storage) to monitor the usage of Cloud Storage for Firebase activity